# groovy - regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, groovy, match

I have this kind of strings:

```
"blabla (label 1 label 2)"
"blabla (label 1 2) blabla"
```

I would like to match "1" and "2" and replace them by "X" to have:

```
"blabla (label X label X)"
"blabla (label X X) blabla"
```

I have this code but it doesn't work as I want.

```
def result = "blabla (label 1 label 2)"
def result = result.findAll(/.+label\s([1-9]).*/) { m -> "X" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replaceAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) instead of `findAll`:

```
def replaced = result.replaceAll(/label(?:\s+\d+)+/) { m ->
    m.replaceAll(/\d+/, "X")
}
```

Comment: if I have 'blabla 1 (label 1 label 2)' the result will be 'blabla X (label X label X)'. This is not what I expected: the result should be: 'blabla 1 (label X label X)' or 'blabla 1 (label X label X) blabla'.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for 'blabla (label 1 label 2)', but for 'blabla (label 1 2) blabla' I had 'blabla (label X 2) blabla'.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the regex ends with `.*` which hoovers up everything after the first label.

Start `groovysh`, then run:

```
input = "blabla (label 1 label 2)"

input.findAll ( /label\s([1-9])\b/ ) { m -> "X" }

===> [X, X]
```

Comment: Ok but I need to have the all input like 'blabla (label X label X)' not just [X,X]. Or maybe I didn't understand your answer..

Comment: Yes, but if you use .* at the end of the regex, your findAll() will never match "label 2" because it will have matched "label 1" ... and everything that comes after, i.e. "label 1 label 2)". And then end. This is why you get just one "X" instead of the expected two in the printout.